# ESLint define folder in config file. (Ignore all but..., Include only...)

Tags: javascript, eslint

How to set the folder to lint in the `.eslintrc.json` file, instead after the `eslint` command in `package.json`.

**package.json** (snippet)

```
"scripts: {
  "lint": "eslint ./src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
}
```

I want only:

```
"scripts: {
  "lint": "eslint",
}
```

and define the path and ext in the `.eslintrc.json`.

Alternativ, set `.eslintignore` to ignore `ALL` but not `./src`.
I only want to lint the src-folder. Not the root. 
Also for the `eslint` plugin of `vscode`.

My current solution:

**.eslintignore**

```
/*
!/src
```

But I wondering, why is there no option in the config files to set the folder/s to lint.
I'm looking for the most common and elegant solution.
Maybe it sounds like a duplicate here. But I searched a lot of topics and found nothing similar to solve my problem.

Comment: Your solution with eslintignore is the best I have found so far, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I've adapted your solution with the `.eslintignore` file and put the rules directly into my config file's `ignorePatterns` option (`.eslintrc.cjs` in my case). Works like a charm for me:

```
module.exports = {
  ignorePatterns: ['/*', '!/src']
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set in **overrides** inside `.eslintrc.json`

> If you specified directories with CLI (e.g., eslint lib), ESLint searches target files in the directory to lint. The target files are *.js or the files that match any of **overrides** entries (but exclude entries that are any of files end with *).

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"]
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["bin/*.js", "lib/*.js"],
      "excludedFiles": "*.test.js",
      "rules": {
        "quotes": ["error", "single"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Refer: document of [Configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#example-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **@billythetalented**'s comment I had to add a dot in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "lint": "eslint .",
   ...
}
```

Otherwise, It didn't lint anything